# Raphael not attaching to to div

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to build a website using Raphael. [You could see what my website looks like over here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBD6k.png) (I used the Google Chrome inspector to highlight where the canvas is being made). I created a div with an id tag of 'clock'(which is coloured red in the example image). This following is the javascript code.

```
$(function() {
    var paper = Raphael('clock', 50, 50, 0, 0);
    var c = paper.circle(17, 17, 15);
});
```

Raphael does a couple of things wrong. First, it's not in the div nor in the size I told it to be. Second, all the xml code is placed at the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` tag. Third and most odd, the circle appears on every page. Even the ones without the 'circle' div.

I don't know if this matters, but this website is being developed on the liftweb framework. I noticed how it changes characters in the file, so I used an externally hosted Raphael file. It made no difference.

Thanks for reading

Comment: First argument of Raphael constructor might be HTMLElement, not a string. Try: `var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('clock'), 50, 50, 0, 0);`

Comment: Interesting, didn't see that in the tutorial I followed. But in the end, it made no difference.

Comment: Nevermind, caching caused the changes to not take effect. It works now. Thanks.